# How to fetch places suggestion from Google API to autocompletetextview

Tags: java, android, sdk, maps

I have this:

````xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
    android:background="@drawable/auto_bg"
    android:id="@+id/location_auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:hint="Enter location"
    android:fontFamily="@font/biennale_regular"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/dark4"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />
    ```

and I want a suggestion of places from Google API to the autocomplete textview in Java if there is a full example that would be helpful.
````